# Highcharts - Area chart advanced layering

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'd like to have a version of a [basic area](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-basic) graph where the layering works not by adding one chart and then overlaying a second chart, but instead for every x value, a colored line is drawn from the higher chart's y coordinate to the y coordinate vertically below on the lower chart, and then a different colored line is drawn from this lower chart's y coordinate to the x axis.

Here's images of first the default chart and then my edits as examples.

[image: The default behavior]

[image: What I would like]

I anticipate having potentially many charts on one page (anywhere from 1-5,7,10 who knows). And the reason I'm not just putting the "smaller" of the two charts on a higher layer than the "larger" is that they could swap positions over time. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9IIe.jpg) for two data sets that that swap in which chart has larger values. I'm leaning towards not allowing transparent charts like the default behavior because when many charts of different colors are overlaid their colors mesh together and become difficult to discern.

Is what I've described possible? Are there alternative ways I could accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that kind of chart is supported by Highcharts. If you would like to get something similar you can ask for it on Highcharts service: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api

Comment: Sean, you could achieve the draft image you showed above using some programming logic and extra series, but it could be awkward for data coming from a database and especially so for the number of series per chart (which you've indicated could be high). Have you considered another type of chart altogether? I'm interested in learning what your use case is for an area chart vs. another type.

Comment: @Mike The area graphs look good for two other view I have, cumulative messages by time [that stack](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked/grid-light), but I guess area charts wouldn't be the most efficient when the data isn't stacking and is very similar, hence high levels of overlap. On second thought for non stacking charts a basic line graph should suffice.